# Какое наименьшее кол-во скобок нужно добавить куда и каких, чтобы последовательность стала верной

Tags: python, алгоритм

Всем привет. Не думал, что эта задача станет непосильной. В общем, есть строчка например ([)] и вот нужно определить какие скобки нужно добавить и куда, а еще и сколько, при условии, что нужно добавить минимальное кол-во. То есть из ([)] должно стать это - ()[()], а не это -()[], в первой случае мы добавляем 2 скобки, а во втором 4. Я решил задачу на половину, у меня добавляется минимальное кол-во скобок, а просто после каждой (или перед) добавляется недостающая скобка. Это тот еще конечно Франкенштейн:

```
def amount_add(seq):
    open_brackets = ('(', '[', '{')
    close_brackets = (')', ']', '}')
    brackets = (')', '(', ']', '[', '{', '}')
    res = []
    pos = ''

    bracket_abbr = {
        '(': 'oR',
        '[': 'oS',
        '{': 'oC',
        ')': 'cR',
        ']': 'cS',
        '}': 'cC',
    }

    abbr_bracket = {
        'oR': '(',
        'oS': '[',
        'oC': '{',
        'cR': ')',
        'cS': ']',
        'cC': '}',
    }

    for i in range(len(seq)):
        if seq[i] in open_brackets:
            pos += seq[i] + '.' + bracket_abbr[close_brackets[open_brackets.index(seq[i])]] + '.'
        else:
            pos += bracket_abbr[open_brackets[close_brackets.index(seq[i])]] + '.' + seq[i] + '.'

    pos = list(filter(lambda x: x != '', pos.split('.')))  # убираем пробелы

    for i in range(len(pos)):
        if not(pos[i] in brackets):
            res.append([i, abbr_bracket[pos[i]]])

    strs = ''

    for i in res:
        strs += i[1]

    return res


a = '((}(})'  # ((){}(){})
x = '([)]'  # ()[()]
b = '(]]'  # ()[][]
c = '(({{[['  # (({{[[]]}}))
d = '{)['  # {}()[]
e = ')('  # ()()
f = ']}{[(])('  # []{}{}[()]()()

for i in (a, x, b, c, d, e, f):
    print(f'{i} -> {amount_add(i)}')
```

В задании непонятно, относительно чего считать индекс, так что я считал индекс, как будто предыдущие я уже добавлял.
Был вариант с другом сделать тупой перебор, но даже на 4 скобках было бы не очень быстро
Ответ выводится в виде [..., [index, bracket], ...]
Помогите разобраться пожалуйста

Comment: Мысль: если на входе правильная скобочная последовательность, её не нужно менять. Значит любое правильное решение в частности умеет опознавать правильные скобочные последовательности. Тогда логично строить исправляющий алгоритм на базе проверяющего алгоритма.

Comment: Возможен еще вариант ([()]).

Comment: Что-то напоминает - как получить сбалансированное бинарное дерево. Вот еще попытки решения https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64218609/minimum-add-to-make-parentheses-string-consisting-of

Comment: Я бы через регулярки решал. Понятно, что долго, да и писать это муторно, но с другой стороны, это будет проще, чем остальные варианты